# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#, string, int

I'm doing an athlete program and I want to make int salaryCounter = athleteSalary.ToString so when the user enters the salary of the hired professional I can subtract it from the salary of the athlete and print out how much the athlete will have left but when I try to do it the program tells me "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' ". Can someone help me?

```
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first name of the athlete");
    String athleteString = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second name of the athlete");
    String athleteString2 = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Did you type {0} {1}? Press y for yess n for no.", athleteString.ToString(), athleteString2.ToString());
    ConsoleKeyInfo KeyInfo = Console.ReadKey();

    if (KeyInfo.KeyChar == 'y')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the salary of {0} {1}", athleteString.ToString(), athleteString2.ToString());
        String athleteSalary = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Is this right?", athleteSalary.ToString());
        ConsoleKeyInfo rightathleteSalary = Console.ReadKey();
        int salaryCounter = athleteSalary.ToString();

        if (rightathleteSalary.KeyChar == 'y')
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Ok. Lets contiune.");
             athleteSalary = Convert.ToString(salaryCounter);
             Console.WriteLine(salaryCounter);

             int counter = 0;

             Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", athleteString.ToString(), athleteString2.ToString(), salaryCounter.ToString());
             Console.WriteLine("Enter the hired help. The max number of people is five. Press any key to start.");

             while (counter < 5)
             {
                 Console.ReadKey();
                 Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first name of the hired help");
                 String hiredhelpString = Console.ReadLine();
                 Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Last name of the hired help");
                 String hiredhelpString2 = Console.ReadLine();
                 Console.WriteLine("Did you type {0} {1}? Press y for yess n for no.", hiredhelpString.ToString(), hiredhelpString2.ToString());
                 ConsoleKeyInfo KeyInfo5 = Console.ReadKey();

                 if (KeyInfo5.KeyChar == 'y')
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Enter the salary of {0} {1}", hiredhelpString.ToString(), hiredhelpString2.ToString());
                     String hiredhelpSalary = Console.ReadLine();
                     Console.WriteLine("{0} Is this right?", hiredhelpSalary.ToString());
                     ConsoleKeyInfo rightSalary = Console.ReadKey();

                     if (rightSalary.KeyChar == 'y')
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine("Ok. Lets contiune.");
                     }
                     Console.WriteLine("Record this proffesional? Press y for yess n for no.");
                     ConsoleKeyInfo RecordKey = Console.ReadKey();

                     if (RecordKey.KeyChar == 'y')
                     {
                         counter = counter + 1;
                         Console.WriteLine("Number of hired help is {0} They will be paid {1}", counter, hiredhelpSalary);
                         Console.WriteLine("Press any key to contiune.");
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         if (RecordKey.KeyChar == 'n')
                         {
                             counter = counter - 1;
                             Console.WriteLine(" Ok. Lets try again. Press any key to contiune.");
                             Console.ReadKey();
                             Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first name of the hired help");
                             String hiredhelpString3 = Console.ReadLine();
                             Console.WriteLine(" Please enter the Last name of the hired help");
                             String hiredhelpString4 = Console.ReadLine();
                             Console.WriteLine("Did you type {0} {1}? Press y for yess n for no.", hiredhelpString.ToString(), hiredhelpString2.ToString());
                             ConsoleKeyInfo KeyInfo6 = Console.ReadKey();

                             if (KeyInfo6.KeyChar == 'y')
                             {
                                 Console.WriteLine("Record this proffesional? Press y for yess n for no.");
                                 ConsoleKeyInfo RecordKey1 = Console.ReadKey();
                                 if (RecordKey.KeyChar == 'y')
                                 {
                                     counter = counter + 1;
                                     Console.WriteLine("Number of Hired help is {0} press any key to contiune", counter);
                                     Console.WriteLine("Press any key to contiune.");
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                            /*******************************************************************************************************/
                            /************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (KeyInfo5.KeyChar == 'n')
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(" Ok. Lets try again. Press any key to contiune.");
                                Console.ReadKey();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    /*************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("Athlete's name: {0} {1} Number of Hired help is {2}", athleteString.ToString(), athleteString2.ToString(), counter);
                    Console.ReadKey();


            }
```

Comment: I think it's pretty clear. You're using `.ToString()` with an int. You just can't do that, and the error message is extremely clear. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Well, even if I get rid of the **.ToString()**  the error still comes up. I want to record the salary of the athlete and the professionals and subtract the salaries of the professionals from the athlete's salary.

Comment: if/when you convert a number to a string, you wont be able to `subtract it from the salary...`. Do math on numbers not strings

Comment: @nyc1226 that's because you should convert String to int (Int32). Try using int.Parse(string) method.

Comment: Try using direct casting `(int)`, or one of these: `int.Parse(string)`, `int.TryParse(string, out int)`, or `Convert.ToInt32(string)` methods...

Comment: I think @RufusL got the point!

Comment: @RufusL, I tried what you suggested and I'm still getting errors. Can you show me how I would use the methods?

Comment: Sure, added a (very long) answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're getting confused about variable types. Briefly;

string - stores information character by character. The compiler can't read numbers stored in strings.

int - stores whole numeric values which can be used in calculations.

Your immediate compile problem comes from this line;

```
int salaryCounter = athleteSalary.ToString();
```

You're telling the compiler to take altheteSalary which is a string, call the ToString() method which gets the string representation (this is unnecessary when the source is a string) and store the result in an integer.

You need to parse the string to read out the numeric value like this;

```
int salaryCounter = int.Parse(athleteSalary)
```

Though, whenever you receive input directly from a user you should code defensively, so instead of int.Parse, use TryParse. That way if your user enters 'Bob' for their salary, you can display an appropriate error;

```
int salaryCounter;
while(!int.TryParse(athleteSalary, out salaryCounter)
{
    Console.Writeline("The salary should be a number, try again");
    athleteSalary = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Also, you can remove most of the calls to .ToString(), especially where the variable is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you need to convert your user input to a type other than a string.

There are many ways to do this, but since you are writing a console application that relies heavily on user-entered data, and since some of this data has to be converted to types other than strings, you might consider writing some helper methods that take care of some of the converting and retrying for you.

I've used the following class in several applications with success. Basically, it's just a bunch of methods that accept a string 'prompt' and return a strongly typed result from the user. If the user enters invalid data, then they have to try again until the enter something valid:

```
class UserInput
{
    public static bool GetBool(string prompt)
    {
        bool result;

        List<string> validTrueResponses = 
            new List<string> {"yes", "y", "true", "t", "affirmative", 
                "ok", "okay", "yea", "yeah", "yep"};

        List<string> validFalseResponses = 
            new List<string> {"no", "n", "false", "f", "negative", 
                "never", "not", "nay", "nix"};

        while (true)
        {
            if (prompt != null) Console.Write(prompt);
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (validTrueResponses.Any(r => 
                r.Equals(input, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) return true;

            if (validFalseResponses.Any(r => 
                r.Equals(input, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) return false;

            if (bool.TryParse(input, out result)) break;

            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, I don't understand that response. " +
                "Please try again.");
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string GetString(string prompt)
    {
        if (prompt != null) Console.Write(prompt);
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static int GetInt(string prompt)
    {
        int input;

        while (true)
        {
            if (prompt != null) Console.Write(prompt);
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input)) break;
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, that is not valid. Please try again.");
        }

        return input;
    }

    public static decimal GetDecimal(string prompt)
    {
        decimal input;

        while (true)
        {
            if (prompt != null) Console.Write(prompt);
            if (decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input)) break;
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, that is not valid. Please try again.");
        }

        return input;
    }
}
```

Then, I would create a simple class to represent a `Person`, which has simply a first name, last name, and salary (and override the `ToString` method to display first and last name):

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
    }
}
```

Now we can reduce some duplicated code by creating methods to get a `Person` name and salary. This will prompt the user for the information, and then give them a chance to correct it before commiting the data:

```
private static void GetPersonName(Person person, string typeOfPerson)
{
    if (person == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("person");
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(typeOfPerson)) typeOfPerson = "person";

    bool inputIsGood = false;

    while (!inputIsGood)
    {
        person.FirstName = UserInput.GetString(
            string.Format("Please enter the first name of the {0}: ", typeOfPerson));

        person.LastName = UserInput.GetString(
            string.Format("Please enter the last name of the {0}: ", typeOfPerson));

        Console.WriteLine("You entered: {0}", person);
        inputIsGood = UserInput.GetBool("Is that correct (y/n): ");
    }
}

private static void GetPersonSalary(Person person)
{
    bool inputIsGood = false;

    while (!inputIsGood)
    {
        person.Salary = UserInput.GetDecimal(
            string.Format("Enter the salary of {0}: $", person));

        Console.WriteLine("You entered: {0:C}", person.Salary);
        inputIsGood = UserInput.GetBool("Is that correct (y/n): ");
    }
}
```

That may seem like a lot of code, but here's how you can use it in your application:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var athlete = new Person();

    GetPersonName(athlete, "athlete");
    GetPersonSalary(athlete);

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the hired help. The max number of people is five. " +
        "Press any key to start.");

    Console.ReadKey();

    List<Person> hiredHelpers = new List<Person>();

    while (hiredHelpers.Count <= 5)
    {
        bool addAnotherHelper =
            UserInput.GetBool(
                string.Format("There are currently {0} helpers. " +
                    "Do you want to add another (y/n): ",
                    hiredHelpers.Count));

        if (!addAnotherHelper) break;

        Person helper = new Person();

        GetPersonName(helper, "helper");
        GetPersonSalary(helper);

        bool recordHelper = UserInput.GetBool("Do you want to record this " +
            "professional (y/n): ");

        if (recordHelper)
        {
            hiredHelpers.Add(helper);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Athlete's name: {0}, salary: {1:C}.", athlete, athlete.Salary);
    Console.WriteLine("Number of Hired help is: {0}", hiredHelpers.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("Hired help details:");
    hiredHelpers.ForEach(h => 
        Console.WriteLine(" - Name: {0}, Salary: {1:C}", h, h.Salary));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```